# How to scroll through each Datagrid Item on button click wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` and two up and down buttons so  that the user can scroll through each datagrid item on button click; either up or down. How do I go about doing this? I have tried `SelectedIndex` but doesn't seem to work for `DataGrid`.

ExampleCode:

```
    private void btnDownCheckedMedication_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MedicationCheckedInDatagrid.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            MedicationCheckedInDatagrid.SelectedIndex = MedicationCheckedInDatagrid.SelectedIndex - 1;
        }
    }

    private void btnUpCheckedMedication_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MedicationCheckedInDatagrid.SelectedIndex = MedicationCheckedInDatagrid.SelectedIndex + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some sample code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly had it... use `SelectedItem` instead:

```
private void btnDownCheckedMedication_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    if(dataGrid.SelectedIndex > 0 ) {
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.SelectedIndex - 1];
    }
}

private void btnUpCheckedMedication_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    if(dataGrid.SelectedIndex < dataGrid.Items.Count - 1) {
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.SelectedIndex + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I get the error:    Index 2 is either negative or above rows count. for datagrid.selectedIndex+1

Comment: Ah sorry, I think it should have been `dataGrid.Items.Count - 1`... I've updated the answer.